# hiveserver2 (on spark) - "mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input files to process" - why single threaded?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-s3, hive, mapreduce

I have setup Hive (v2.3.4) on Spark (exec engine). My external hive table is Parquet format on s3 across 100s of partitions.     Below settings are set to 20:

```
hive.exec.input.listing.max.threads
    mapred.dfsclient.parallelism.max
    mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.list-status.num-threads
```

Run a simple query:

```
select * from s.there h_code = 'KGD78' and h_no = '265'
```

I can see the below in HiveServer2 logs (the logs continue for more than 1000 lines listing all the different partitions). Why is the listing of files not being done in parallel? It takes more than 5mins just in the listing.

```
2019-03-29T11:29:26,866  INFO [3fa82455-7853-4c4b-8964-847c00bec708 HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-53] compress.CodecPool: Got brand-new decompressor [.snappy]
2019-03-29T11:29:27,283  INFO [3fa82455-7853-4c4b-8964-847c00bec708 HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-53] mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input files to process : 1
2019-03-29T11:29:27,797  INFO [3fa82455-7853-4c4b-8964-847c00bec708 HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-53] mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input files to process : 1
2019-03-29T11:29:28,374  INFO [3fa82455-7853-4c4b-8964-847c00bec708 HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-53] mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input files to process : 1
2019-03-29T11:29:28,919  INFO [3fa82455-7853-4c4b-8964-847c00bec708 HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-53] mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input files to process : 1
2019-03-29T11:29:29,483  INFO [3fa82455-7853-4c4b-8964-847c00bec708 HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-53] mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input files to process : 1
2019-03-29T11:29:30,003  INFO [3fa82455-7853-4c4b-8964-847c00bec708 HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-53] mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input files to process : 1
2019-03-29T11:29:30,518  INFO [3fa82455-7853-4c4b-8964-847c00bec708 HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-53] mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input files to process : 1
2019-03-29T11:29:31,001  INFO [3fa82455-7853-4c4b-8964-847c00bec708 HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-53] mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input files to process : 1
2019-03-29T11:29:31,549  INFO [3fa82455-7853-4c4b-8964-847c00bec708 HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-53] mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input files to process : 1
2019-03-29T11:29:32,048  INFO [3fa82455-7853-4c4b-8964-847c00bec708 HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-53] mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input files to process : 1
2019-03-29T11:29:32,574  INFO [3fa82455-7853-4c4b-8964-847c00bec708 HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-53] mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input files to process : 1
2019-03-29T11:29:33,130  INFO [3fa82455-7853-4c4b-8964-847c00bec708 HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-53] mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input files to process : 1
2019-03-29T11:29:33,639  INFO [3fa82455-7853-4c4b-8964-847c00bec708 HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-53] mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input files to process : 1
2019-03-29T11:29:34,189  INFO [3fa82455-7853-4c4b-8964-847c00bec708 HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-53] mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input files to process : 1
2019-03-29T11:29:34,743  INFO [3fa82455-7853-4c4b-8964-847c00bec708 HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-53] mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input files to process : 1
2019-03-29T11:29:35,208  INFO [3fa82455-7853-4c4b-8964-847c00bec708 HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-53] mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input files to process : 1
2019-03-29T11:29:35,701  INFO [3fa82455-7853-4c4b-8964-847c00bec708 HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-53] mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input files to process : 1
2019-03-29T11:29:36,183  INFO [3fa82455-7853-4c4b-8964-847c00bec708 HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-53] mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input files to process : 1
2019-03-29T11:29:36,662  INFO [3fa82455-7853-4c4b-8964-847c00bec708 HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-53] mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input files to process : 1
2019-03-29T11:29:37,154  INFO [3fa82455-7853-4c4b-8964-847c00bec708 HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-53] mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input files to process : 1
2019-03-29T11:29:37,645  INFO [3fa82455-7853-4c4b-8964-847c00bec708 HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-53] mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input files to process : 1
```

I've tried

```
hive.exec.input.listing.max.threads
    mapred.dfsclient.parallelism.max
    mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.list-status.num-threads
```

with defaults, 1, 50...still same result

Comment: what is the size of your cluster ?

Comment: 5 nodes, 64cpu, 488gb ram each

Comment: https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-21546